# Terminate all observables and wait until they're complete

Tags: system.reactive, rx-swift

I want to write a function that wraps an observable in a way I can terminate it, and perform some code after it completes. I thought of doing:

```
class ObsrevableWrapper {

  var terminating: Bool = false
  var terminatingObservable: Observable<Int>?
  func wrapObservable(o: Observable<Int>) -> Observable<Int> {
    terminatingObservable = Observable
      .deferred { () -> Observable<Int> in
        if self.terminating {
          return Observable.empty()
        } else {
          return o
        }
      }
      .takeWhile {_ in
        return !self.terminating
      }
      .publish().refCount()

    return terminatingObservable!
  }

  func terminateObservable() {
    terminating = true
    terminatingObservable!
      .map { _ -> Void in
        return ()
      }
      .ignoreElements()
      .concat(Observable.just(()))
      .subscribeNext {
        self.output("Performing completion code")
    }
  }

}
```

Can I do it without the `var terminating: Bool` instance variable? (i.e. more functional..)

Comment: How about declaring `terminating` as an `Observable` ? (Atleast) In Rx.NET we have an overload for `TakeWhile` which accepts `Observable`  parameter

Comment: The problem is not in the `takeWhile` (`takeUntil` does accept an observable). It's in the `deferred`. The subscription in `terminateObservable` may trigger a subscription in the input observable if the user of `wrapObservable(o:)` does not subscribe. When using an observable to stop the sequence (like `takeUntil`), the emission happens asynchronously, and I'm not guaranteed (AFAIK) that when I immediately subscribe (after the `connect` etc.) in `terminateObservable` it won't trigger an undesired subscription in the input observable `o: Observable<Int>` before the `takeUntil` prevents it.